# Number of ways of arranging crosses and zeroes up to cyclic permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Assume we have $n$ crosses ( $\times$ ) and $m$ zeroes ( 0 ). I want to find in how many ways we can arrange them up to cyclic permutations for any $n,m$. For instance, for $n = 3$ and $m = 3$ I believe we have four cases,

$0\; 0\;0 \times\times\,\times$

$0\; 0 \times 0 \times\times$

$0\; 0 \times \times\, 0\, \times$

$0 \times 0\times 0 \,\times$

If $n = 2$ (or $m = 2$), then I think we have $\lceil \frac{n + m - 1}{2} \rceil$ possibilities. My best guess was to obtain a general formula by recursion and then hope to be able to sum whatever comes out, but haven't managed so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Burnside's lemma?

Comment: [MSE Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has a list of these types of problems. Look for necklaces (cyclic) and bracelets (dihedral).

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware about the necklaces and bracelets nomenclature and methods and the Burnside lemma. I'll look into it!